# React is not updating the view template after updating the state in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, server-side-rendering, setstate, use-state

I am trying to update the the state by `onPress` event state has been updated but view is not changing

```
<View style={styles.dropDownMenu}>
                {
                    dataLoaded ?
                        retrivedData.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                                    let changedState = retrivedData
                                    changedState.map((dataItem) => {
                                        if(dataItem.id == item.id){
                                            dataItem.checked = !dataItem.checked
                                            console.info('data matched')
                                        }
                                    })
                                    setRetrivedData(changedState,console.log(retrivedData));
                                }} >
                                    <View key={item.id}>
                                        <View style={styles.menus} key={item.id}>
                                            <Text style={[{ fontWeight: 'normal', color: 'black' }, styles.menuTitle]}>{item.name}</Text>
                                            <Icon style={styles.icon} name={'chevron-small-down'} type='entypo' />
                                            <Text>{item.checked ? 'True' : 'False'}</Text>
                                        </View>
                                    </View>
                                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                            )
                        }) :
                        <Text>NULL</Text>
                }
            </View>
```

what I have to change i dont know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
       let changedState = [...retrivedData]; // Try this way
        .....
       setRetrivedData(changedState,console.log(retrivedData));
    }} >
       ......
 </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not go through your logic but I see an error in your .map loop.

.map returns an array. so you need to change to this.

Change from this

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
                                    let changedState = retrivedData
                                    changedState.map((dataItem) => {
                                        if(dataItem.id == item.id){
                                            dataItem.checked = !dataItem.checked
                                            console.info('data matched')
                                        }
                                    })
                                    setRetrivedData(changedState,console.log(retrivedData));
                                }} >
```

to this.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setRetrivedData(retrivedData.map((dataItem) => dataItem.id == item.id ? { ...dataItem, checked: !dataItem.checked } : dataItem
)) }>
```

You use tenary operator, if it the ID matches, toggle the checked true/false, if not then return the unmodified object.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

State mutation and not returning updated array. The saved state reference is saved back into state.

```
onPress={() => {
  let changedState = retrivedData; // <-- state reference

  changedState.map((dataItem) => { // <-- map return not saved
    if (dataItem.id == item.id) {
      dataItem.checked = !dataItem.checked; // <-- state mutation
      console.info("data matched"); // <-- missing map return
    }
  });
  setRetrivedData(changedState, console.log(retrivedData)); // <-- setRetrivedData accepts single argument
}}
```

## Solution

1. Map existing state array to a new array
2. Copy element being updated

Handler

```
onPress={() => {
  setRetrivedData((retrivedData) =>
    retrivedData.map((dataItem) => {
      if (dataItem.id == item.id) {
        dataItem.checked = !dataItem.checked;
        return {
          ...dataItem,
          checked: !dataItem.checked
        };
      }
      return dataItem;
    })
  );
}}
```